raised unexpected: TypeError('send_verification() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given') in celery
class CreateAccountView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        email = request.data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return Response({"message": "User with this email already exists"},    status=status.HTTP_203_NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION)
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            domain = request.get_host()
            **send_verification.delay(email,domain)**
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"message": "Check your email to verify your account"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@shared_task(bind=True)
def send_verification(self,email,domain):
    print(email)
    try:
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        token = generate_token(email)
        verify_url = f'http://{domain}{reverse("verify_email", args=[token])}'
        subject = 'Verify your email address'
        message = f'Click the link to verify your email: {verify_url}'
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, [email])
        print(message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error sending email: {e}')
    print("Done")
    return "Done"

when i was try to send a verification link through celery and pass 2 arguments to the send_verification() function but it always says takes 1 positional argumentt and 3 where given

Can you post traceback error?
